# How to use lambda to list tags for resources (accounts)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-organizations

I am working on a project to list all accounts in the organization. I created a lambda function with Read permissions for Organization and I am able to get Accounts using boto3 SDK (list_all_accounts). The problem is that the JSON I get does not provide info about the tag that is assigned for this resource. Is it possible to use Lambda to read the account tag?

I went over boto3 documentation and I was not able to find a method that would allow me to do it https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/organizations.html

I am able to get tags of accounts using CLI
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/APIReference/API_ListTagsForResource.html

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.12.6/reference/services/organizations.html#Organizations.Client.list_tags_for_resource

Comment: I dumb... Idk how I missed it. Thank you...

Comment: You linked to an older version of the boto3 @imported. 1.9.42 in this version there was no support for list_tag_for_resources. Jordan linked to 1.12.6